# Checking if dropdowns are null or not

Tags: c#, winforms

This falls over on the first elseif. Basically I have a load of dropdowns and I'm trying to work out which filters to select based on if people have selected the dropdown items or not.

[image]

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
```

Based On

```
 private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddCompany.SelectedItem.ToString() == null && ddStatus.SelectedItem.ToString() == null)
        {
            UpdateTicketsList("NO", "NO");
        }
        else if (ddCompany.SelectedItem.ToString() != null && ddStatus.SelectedItem.ToString() == null)
        {
            UpdateTicketsList(ddCompany.SelectedItem.ToString(), "NO");
        }
        else if (ddCompany.SelectedItem.ToString() == null && ddStatus.SelectedItem.ToString() != null)
        {
            UpdateTicketsList("NO", ddStatus.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why use `.ToString()` calls in the `if`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `ToString` on a `null` object will result in a `NullReferenceException`.

Remove the calls to `ToString` in your if-statement expression and your code should work as expected :)